# SQL query for Finding data with join or where within same table from multi tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Im sorry i cant explain the question

I have a problem that i need to join 4 tables together to find some information. Im using inner join which is bringing me the right data but duplicate row having a minor change data. Lets say im getting this data

[See the Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrIjp.png)

If we look at the results. At the last 4 rows we can notice simillar results. What i want to achieve is these 4 rows converted into 2.

I only want rows whose account id = vehicle account id and 110. I want these two rows.  The join query i write is as follows

```
 select Distinct vh.VehicleNo,jd.AccountID, tr.ID,jd.Memo,je.Description, jd.Cr,jd.Dr ,jd.Detail, je.JEntryId,      je.ExpenseID from tbl_JDetail jd
 inner join tbl_JEntry je on je.JEntryId = jd.JEntryID
 inner join tbl_Trip tr on tr.ID = je.RefID
 inner join tbl_Vehciles vh on vh.VID = tr.VehicleID
```

I really need to achieve this.. Any help would be appreciated how can i achieve. What i want is let me write the query in simple langauge

The query should first find rows in jdetail with accountid = 110. Then get its  jentryid . Then in Jentry it should find the tripid and in trip table i have the vehicle id. Vehicle table contains vehicle id.

Then the query should find in jdetail with same jentryid and vehicleaccountid

i need jdetail accountid = 110 and accountid = vehicle.accountid

The vehicle relation is Jdetail > Jentry > Trip > Vehicle

i hope i was clear enough

Comment: have you tried to `GROUP BY ` the field you need to group your results by ?

Comment: Yes i did but it doesnot achieve the result

Comment: so, do you only need results where  "jdetail has accountid = 110" ?

Comment: Right i need jdetail accountid = 110 and  accountid = vehicle accountid

Whose relation is Jentry > Trip > Vehicle

Comment: juste add a where clause to your query: ..... where vehicle.accountid=110

Comment: lets say we have vehicle id =3345
and im querying jd.accountid = 110. It will list me multiple lines. Now i have to check the results with same jentry id. Lets say we have 4 records of same jentry. Now i want it to find jdetail row whose accountid is vehicle account id

Comment: Please add any relevant information in your question. People reading your question need to know this and not all are digging thru comments. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70861471/edit)

Comment: Please add sample data to your question in the form of text, not as an image. Some people want to use your testdata to test an answer before posting it, don't expect them to type it all from an image

Answer (score 0):

Please add supporting information (create table statements, sample data, current output and desired output) to your question. As you have not included supporting information, I am unable to test this.  This is my "best guess" based on your description.

```sql
select Distinct vh.VehicleNo,jd.AccountID, tr.ID,jd.Memo,je.Description, jd.Cr,jd.Dr ,jd.Detail, je.JEntryId,      je.ExpenseID
from tbl_JDetail jd
inner join tbl_JEntry je
    on je.JEntryId = jd.JEntryID
inner join tbl_Trip tr
    on tr.ID = je.RefID
inner join tbl_Vehciles vh
    on vh.VID = tr.VehicleID
    and vh.AccountID = jd.AccountID
where jd.AccountID = 110
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved it by using 2 CTEs. CTE1 finds the jentry_id of all records using account ID = 110

and CTE2 find all the required data with inner join cte on cte.JEntryId = jd.JEntryID

It solved all my problems..

Thankyou. Hope it help someone else too

Comment: This is not an answer. You do not show the solution, only a vague description on how to solve it. Please update your question with all requested information and please update this answer so it shows the exact solution

Comment: Sorry for the confustion. I will add it ASAP